# passing a Function0<boolean> from Java to Scala

Tags: scala

I have a scala file with the following function:

```
def whitelist(shouldSample: => Boolean = true)
```

Now, in Java code, I'd like to pass in a Function0 as an argument:

```
Function0<Boolean> filterFunction = new AbstractFunction0<Boolean>() {
  @Override
  public Boolean apply() {
    return true;
  }
};

ThriftEndpointSampler.whitelist(filterFunction);
```

Intellij complains that `filterFunction` isn't parameterized with the Java `boolean` primitive, which I can't do, since it's a primitive. The compiler complains too, requesting that `filterFunction` be parameterized with `java.lang.Object`. Using `Object` in place of Boolean works for the compiler, but Intellij still complains. `scala.Boolean` doesn't really work, since I thought Java `boolean`s are automatically converted to scala `Boolean` primitives.

Using `Object` seems really strange to me. Is there some better practice for doing this?

Comment: I think this happens because `AbstractFunction0` is specialized by Scala compiler for various primitives, including boolean. Actual class name taken by `whitelist()` should actually be `scala.Function0$mcZ$sp`, or, in Java case, `scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0$mcZ$sp`. But IDEA won't allow you to use this class directly for some reason, so I don't know how to solve your problem. Sorry :(